# What R function can be used instead of box.tidewell() when a lot of predictors need to be transformed?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am doing a multiple regression on a data set containing one dependent variables and 13 independent variables.

The `box.tidewell()` method only works for the first 6 predictors after which it reaches the maximum number of iterations.

I tried changing the number of `max.inter` in the argument, but the following error is displayed: `Error in lm.fit(cbind(1, x1.p, x2), y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf dans 'x'`.

By the way, I tried the following:

`boxTidwell(df$density~df$age+df$weight+df$height+df$neck+df$chest+df$abdomen+df$hip+df$thigh+df$knee+df$ankle+df$biceps+df$forearm+df$wrist,data=df)`

and

`boxTidwell(df$density~.,data=df)`

but nothing works.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards, Louis de Vitry

Comment: `box.Tidwell` is not part of base R. Please include the names of any packages that you are using in your question.

Comment: @lmo Thank you for your comment. I meant the function `boxTidwell()` from the car package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a calculated variable (var_c=var_a/var_b) that was causing this error:
error in lm.fit(cbind(1, x.log.x, x1.p, x2), y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

I rounded that variable to get rid of any repeating decimals and this took care of the issue. Ex: NNdata$REPEAT_PRPRTN <- round(NNdata$REPEAT_PRPRTN, digits=2)

I'm not exactly sure why this works but it may be a lead.