# boxTidwell in car package not working

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to use `boxTidwell` in the r package `car` for improving the results of linear regression. However, it always doesn't work. The code is like this:

```
library(car)
boxTidwell(mpg~cyl+disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec, data=mtcars)
```

The result shows that

> "Error in lm.fit(cbind(1, x1.p, x2), y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'"

Could anyone tell me the reason for the error? How can I do to make `boxTidwell` run?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your call.

1. As documentation of `boxTidwell()` shows, you need to provide a **second argument**

> other.x    one-sided formula giving the predictors that are not
>   candidates for transformation, including (e.g.) factors.

Another [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61217/transforming-variables-for-multiple-regression-in-r) mentions that "option `other.x` indicates the terms of the regression that are not to be transformed. This would be all your categorical variables."

So running this code (based on the example in `boxTidwell()`) will work:

```
boxTidwell(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, ~as.factor(am) + poly(gear, 2),
           data = mtcars)
```

2. **Predictors**

For some reason using more than 3 predictors, like in your original example, doesn't work:

```
boxTidwell(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec,
           ~as.factor(am) + poly(gear, 2),
           data = mtcars)
```

> Error in lm.fit(cbind(1, x1.p, x2), y, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533582/what-r-function-can-be-used-instead-of-box-tidewell-when-a-lot-of-predictors-n),  `boxTidwell` works with up to 6 predictors but when I tried running your code with only 4 of them (`cyl + disp + hp + drat`) then it returned an error as well.